# Adding a custom menu to my WordPress theme's top navigation

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add a custom menu to my theme's top navigation.  I have a plugin that , when activated, automatically switches the active theme to this theme that I am currently making. Right now, only the default menu is being displayed. I am not sure if it's an issue with registering the starter content or an issue with displaying the correct menu.  Here is my code:

In ThemeName/functions.php:

```
function theme_support(){

...

register_nav_menus( array(
        'top'    => __( 'Top Menu', 'PinkVulture' )
    ) );

add_theme_support('starter-content', array(
    ...
    'nav_menus' => array(
            // Assign a menu to the "top" location.
            'top' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Top Menu', 'PinkVulture' ),
                'items' => array(
                    'link_home' => array(
                        'title' => 'Home',
                        'url' => site_url()
                    ), // Note that the core "home" page is actually a link in case a static front page is not used.
                    'page_menu' => array(
                        'title' => 'Menu',
                        'url' => site_url('/menu')
                    ),
                    'page_specials' => array(
                        'title' => 'Specials',
                        'url' => site_url('/specials')
                    ),
                    'page_groups' => array(
                        'title' => 'Groups',
                        'url' => site_url('/groups')
                    ),
                    'page_events' => array(
                        'title' => 'Events',
                        'url' => site_url('/events')
                    ),
                    'page_about' => array(
                        'title' => 'About',
                        'url' => site_url('/about')
                    ),
                    'page_contact' => array(
                        'title' => 'Contact',
                        'url' => site_url('/contact')
                    )
                )
            ),
    ...
    ));

}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_support' );
```

In ThemeName/header.php:

```
...
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
                            'theme_location' => 'top'
                        ) ); ?>
                    </ul>
                </nav><!-- .navigation-top -->
...
```

Comment: First of all, the `wp_nav_menu` will print `ul` element as well. Other than that, what do you want to achieve? This should probably print the `top` menu.

Comment: Have you created a new menu in Appearance => Menus, added some menu items and checked the checkbox at the bottom of the menu items which should say 'Top Menu'?